# Laravel 5 update method for different stuff on Resource controller

Tags: controller, resources, laravel-5

I'm doing a project for school and I have a small problem. I want to replace a number in users table ("flag" columns) and I'm having problems calling update  for that.

PS: I can add, edit and delete with no problems.

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

My update method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id, $disable = false)
{
    $user = User::findOrfail($id);

        if($disable){

        $user->flags = 1;
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.index');

    } else {

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            'institution_id' => 'required',

        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return redirect()->route('admin.edit', [$id])->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        $user->name = $request->get('name');
        $user->email = $request->get('email');

        $alt_email = $request->get('alt_email');

        if ($alt_email) {

            $user->alt_email = $alt_email;
        }

        $photo_url = $request->get('photo_url');

        if ($photo_url) {

            $user->photo_url = $photo_url;
        }

        $profile_url = $request->get('profile_url');

        if ($profile_url) {

            $user->profile_url = $profile_url;
        }

        $user->institution_id = $request->get('institution_id');
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
        $user->position = $request->get('position');

        $user->role = $request->get('role');

        $message = ['message_success' => 'User ' . $user->name . ' update successfully!'];

        if (!$user->save()) {

            $message = ['message_error' => 'Failed to create user!'];
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.index')->with($message);
}
```

Button that I want to do the change:

```
<td>
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="color: #ffffff" href="{{route('admin.update',[$user->id, true]) }}"
 >Disable</a>
</td>
```

EDIT:

My Routes:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```

Comment: So, what is the raised error ?

Comment: There's no errors, just a blank page and my link has:

http://10.10.10.10/project/admin/42?1

42 = id
1 = true (I think)

It should redirect me to index page but there is no return.
 
return redirect()->route('admin.index'); it is even not executing neither the update in DB

Comment: You should pass parameter as  `10.10.10.10/project/admin/42/1`
OR 
`10.10.10.10/project/admin/42?disabled=1` and get it as `Input::get('disabled');`

Comment: I can't figure out how to pass parameter as 10.10.10.10/project/admin/42/1 or10.10.10.10/project/admin/42?disabled=1